# Multiple concurrent statements being run on mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I have written a multi threaded Java program which works just fine.  However the data that it prints to the console every second, I want saved to a mySQL database.

My issue is, I can't just use one database connection because it would just bottleneck with queued statements to be executed.

There are hundreds of threads being run at one so I need something like a multi threaded mySQL connection class.

I have briefly looked at DBCP but am not sure would it be suitable or how to implement it.

I would like to know how others have overcome this quite large issue.

Thanks

EDIT: Forgot to mention that this is a Java desktop app, not Java EE

Comment: I am a total neophyte in this field and so cannot answer this question, but would connection and/or thread pooling help in any way? Such as pooling available through Apache?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a Connector/J connection pool, which will host some number of connections and loan them out to threads as they need it.

See here, complete with example:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html

Comment: Thank looks very interesting, it is written for Java EE in the example.  I will look further into this tomorrow